# 'itemprop' and 'rel' attributes on same element

Tags: html, w3c-validation, microdata, rel

Is it valid to use the `itemprop` attribute *and* the `rel` attribute on the same element?

The example from [Google’s Site Name documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitename) contains

> ```
> <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" itemprop="url">
> ```

which gives this error in https://validator.w3.org/nu/:

> Attribute `rel` not allowed on element `link` at this point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the specification.

Microdata, where the `itemprop` attribute is coming from, is [defined by WHATWG’s *HTML*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#microdata) as well as by [W3C’s *HTML Microdata*](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/).

The WHATWG version is a living standard without snapshots (so things might change; my quotes are from 2015-07-25), the W3C version is currently only a [*Working Group Note* from 2013](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/), no *Recommendation*.

For the `a` element and the `area` element:

- both specifications allow to use the attributes `itemprop` and `rel` together

For the `link` element:

- **WHATWG:** it’s **disallowed** to use the attributes together

  [`link` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-link-element):

  > A `link` element must have either a `rel` attribute or an `itemprop` attribute, but not both.
- **W3C:** it’s **allowed** to use the attributes together

  [Content models](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#content-models):

  > If a `link` element has an `itemprop` attribute, the `rel` attribute may be omitted.